# Download files in Android Instant apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to download file via Download Manager in Instant app:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");

DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setTitle("Demo")
            .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                    "test.mp4"));
```

But getting an exception:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/emulated/0/Download
    at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:539)
```

Is there other way to download files in Instant apps?

Comment: Do you have right permissions ?

Comment: There's no WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in Instant apps (https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/faqs)

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems it be related with Android Runtime Permission introduced in Android 6.0

When your app targeting API Level 23, by default all the permission is false you have to request permission dialog and approve the permission before using that into your app.

Ask the permission

```
public class RequestPermissionHandler {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RequestPermissionListener mRequestPermissionListener;
    private int mRequestCode;

public void requestPermission(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode,
        RequestPermissionListener listener) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mRequestCode = requestCode;
    mRequestPermissionListener = listener;

    if (!needRequestRuntimePermissions()) {
        mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        return;
    }
    requestUnGrantedPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
}

private boolean needRequestRuntimePermissions() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
}

private void requestUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    String[] unGrantedPermissions = findUnGrantedPermissions(permissions);
    if (unGrantedPermissions.length == 0) {
        mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        return;
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, unGrantedPermissions, requestCode);
}

private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, permission)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private String[] findUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions) {
    List<String> unGrantedPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
            unGrantedPermissionList.add(permission);
        }
    }
    return unGrantedPermissionList.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
                    return;
                }
            }
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
        } else {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
        }
    }
}

public interface RequestPermissionListener {
    void onSuccess();

    void onFailed();
}
```

Use in Activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RequestPermissionHandler mRequestPermissionHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRequestPermissionHandler = new RequestPermissionHandler();

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handleButtonClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleButtonClicked(){
        mRequestPermissionHandler.requestPermission(this, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, 123, new RequestPermissionHandler.RequestPermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "request permission failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        mRequestPermissionHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add this in your `manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```